# BlackBerry: creating a dynamic no. of buttons based on the contents of a vector

Tags: arrays, blackberry, user-interface, vector, button

based on the contents of a vector(IDs), i'm trying to create the corresponding no. of buttons but I'm having problems doing that. I was wondering if anyone could help?

Below is the code that i'm using to try to get that done...

```
ButtonField[] btn = new ButtonField[list.IDs.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<list.IDs.size(); i++){
            btn[i].setLabel((String)list.IDs.elementAt(i));
            add(btn[i]);
        }
```

I'm currently getting an null pointer exception on the setLabel line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an array (`btn`) of `ButtonField`s but you aren't actually initializing the actual elements of the array.

When you create an array in Java, all of the elements of the array are initially `NULL`.

Try this:

```
ButtonField[] btn = new ButtonField[list.IDs.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<list.IDs.size(); i++){
            btn[i] = new ButtonField(...);
            btn[i].setLabel((String)list.IDs.elementAt(i));
            add(btn[i]);
        }
```

Notice the new line, which sets the array element to an actual object:

```
btn[i] = new ButtonField(...);
```

Of course, you will need to fill in whatever arguments are necessary for the constructor.

Comment: ah I see...thanks! I didn't realse that declaring the array wasn't initialising the buttons.

Comment: Adam: How to set change Listener for all buttons